# Python shutil.move: odd softlinking

Tags: python, linux

A script I wrote was meant to move individual day directories from an old location to a new location with a structure like this:

```
/old/YYYY/MM/DD
/new/YYYY/MM/DD
```

and for another task (unrelated to the moving of data) I created a softlink in the new location like this (this was the first mistake I made):

```
/new/2011/09 -> /old/2011/09
```

My script essential used this function call:

```
for d in os.listdir("/old/2011/09"):
    shutil.move(os.path.join("/old/2011/09/", d), os.path.join("/new/2011/09", d))
```

After running my script 2011/09 was empty in both.  I had this occur at work with unarchived data...big problem.  **My question is why didn't shutil.move() give me an error that the day directory I was moving already existed?**  Each day inside 09 should have been the same directory because of the softlink.

```
/new/2011/09/01 == /old/2011/09/01
```

**Doesn't the shutil.move call check the src and dst before calling shutil.copy2?**  From the docs: "The destination directory must not already exist." or is that only when it uses rename?  AND if it makes a difference both old and new locations were glusterfs.

[shutil.move Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

[shutil.copy Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

Thanks for any clarity you can provide.

**EDIT/UPDATE**: I submitted a question to the python-list asking why this behavior existed and asked if it should be changed ([list archive](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-October/1282155.html)).  They suggested I file a bug report.  While doing the tests to submit the bug I found out that this has been fixed in Python 2.7.  You can see the differences in the source in the move function declaration: [Python 2.6](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b9a95ce2692c/Lib/shutil.py) and [Python 2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d30482d51c25/Lib/shutil.py).

This still does the move/rename but won't magically delete an entire directory.

Comment: `If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.` It seems like you'll have to check for yourself whether or not the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to these two lines in [shutil.move](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d30482d51c25/Lib/shutil.py#l262):

```
        copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
        rmtree(src)
```

where `src='old'` and `real_dst='new/old'`. The `copytree` command copies `old` to the subdirectory `new/old`. That goes fine, although it may not be what you intended.

`rmtree` removes the `old` directory. That's a problem, since `new` is now a dangling symlink.

Comment: The symlink is of the month, not the day.  So the real_dst would become /new/2011/09/01/01/ which is actually /old/2011/09/01/01/.  So if shutil.move used realpath() instead of abspath() (in _destinsrc) I never would have lost data...or I could have just not been dumb and verified that I was doing what I thought I was doing.

Comment: ...or I could have used realpath in my script when creating the full paths.  +1 for link to the source code.